# Intuition behind the definition of Measurable Sets

Tags: measure-theory, intuition, lebesgue-measure

I started studying "Measure Theory and Integration" and went through the first section which talks about Lebesgue Outer Measure of a set. All was well until I started with the second section which starts with the definition of Measurable sets :

** The set $E$ is Lebesgue Measurable if for each set $A$ we have**

$m^*(A)=m^*(A\bigcap E)+m^*(A\bigcap E^c)$

I know the $\leq$ inequality comes from subadditivity.

So it all boils down to showing the $\geq$ inequality.

Though I read the definition and am able to solve questions on the topic. I don't quite understand it *intuitively*. Any help would be appreciated.

Also give me an example where $\geq$ inequality is not satisfied.

Thank you.

Comment: I would say that measurable sets are sets that are split up by any other set on a 'nice' way. If there is more to find on intuition then I will learn from that too. Asking for an example where $\geq$ is not satisfied is the same as asking for a set that is not Lebesgue-measurable.

Comment: I don't know any examples. Can you please tell me one?

Comment: I haven't got them 'in my pocket'. Maybe [this](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~zhang24/NonMeasurableSet.pdf) can help.

Comment: There are different (equivalent) definitions of a measurable set. The one you have showed is named after Caratheodory. Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) will have what you search for, regarding intuition. 

Also, though there are non-lebesgue measurable sets, they are extremely rare, with complex construction, so I don't think they will provide much intuition. For the most part, most sets that you "encounter" are measurable.